# Great Django user model to use with anonymous user

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am creating simple user model with the following fields:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique = True, null = False, blank = True)
    agent = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null = False, blank = False)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length = 100,null = True, blank = True)
    screen_width = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null=True)
    screen_height = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null=True)
    screen_resolution = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null=True)
    browser = models.CharField(max_length = 100,blank = True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True, null = False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False, null = False)

#    Adds the date when the user was first created
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True,null = False)
#    Updates the object every time is is saved
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, null = False)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['agent']

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,**kwargs):
        """
        Creates and saves a User
        """

        last_user = get_user_model().objects.all().last()

        # For first user edge case
        if not last_user:
            username = "anon_1"
        else:
            username = "anon_" + str(last_user.id + 1)

        kwargs["username"] = username

        user = get_user_model().objects.create(**kwargs)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username,password):
        """
        Creates and saves a Superuser with the given username, gender and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username = username
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user
```

This will be used for API purposes with Django REST Framework. I will receive all the needed information from the website upon hitting the endpoint. I am mainly using this User model for analytics purposes, and don't care if not all users are unique. Currently I am using a CustomUserModel, like the one from this website:

> http://buildthis.com/customizing-djangos-default-user-model/

But my question is do I need to do it like this. Because I don't have things like username or password. I identify the user by his user agent, platform and so on, and thus I just think that I don't need to use all the things that django AbstractUser model provides. And I am asking if anyone has done something like this.And how it would be done. I would imagine that ad companies use something like this to track users.

Thank You!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve ?
I don't understand why you don't care about uniqueness of users, are your users registering on your website ?

Comment: @M.Dziwny A user will go on the website and search for something, doesn't matter what it is. The search will hit the api with meta information like user_agent and things. Now, I want to be able to create an "anonymous user" based on given meta information(user's fingerprint)and record the user's searches over time. I have the api and everything. I am just asking if I need to make the user model as complicated as on the website above, since I don't have a password or username.

Comment: @M.Dziwny No they are not registering. I will try to create an anonymous user, using their fingerprint from browser.

Comment: @Brenden1995 What does your current model look like? And what code do you have in place that could be built upon to do what you are looking for? Your main question "do I need to do it like this" is not directly answerable, as it's a bit too broad.

Comment: @KevinBrown I edited my question and kind of tried to elaborate better. I am just trying to understand a better design for something like this. How would ad companies that track their users have their database set up? Even though my project is different, the essence of creating an anonymous account based on users computer profile like platform and user agent is the same. Basically I will create a Token for the user. And save it in the user's cookies so that next time I know who it is. Thank You!

Comment: Does those users will need to authenticate ?
From there, it seems like the use of the authentication backend is overwhelming in your case.